# NodeJS request 404 but browser works fine

Tags: node.js, http, request, http-status-code-404

Why am I getting 404 error response when I try to make this request using NodeJS?

```
// Makes an HTTP request to get the cep data
var HTTPRequest = http.request({
    hostname: "psd-mt.org.br",
    port: 80,
    path: "?page_id=88",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11"
    }
});
```

But acessing the url below using a web browser works fine!

http://psd-mt.org.br/?page_id=88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at my pc to test this, but I think you might need to prefix the path with a forward slash, e.g.

```
path: "/?page_id=88"
```